# WordPress if 404 title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress plugin that has the following code inside *header.php*:

```
<?php
    if (the_subtitle("","", false) == "") {
        the_title();
    } elseif(is_404()) {
        echo "404";
    } else {
        the_subtitle();
    }
?>
```

Basically, this should happen:

1. If subtitle is present, echo subtitle.
2. If no subtitle is present, echo title.
3. If 404, echo "404".

But for some reason, when I locate my *404.php* page, there is nothing displayed. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first check is for `subtitle` and your `404`-page has no `subtitle` then that part of the `if-statement` is triggered and all other checks are skipped. By performing the `404` check first things should work as expected.

```
<?php
    if (is_404()) {
        echo "404";
    } elseif (the_subtitle("","", false) == "") {
        the_title();
    } else {
        the_subtitle();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps it might be valuable to explain as to how the statement changes answers the question.